# DOCUMENT_ROOT thing Don't Seems to work

Tags: php, html, css, subdirectory

As advised, I pasted the following code in one of my pages:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/navMain.php";
```

And, well it shows off the following errors:

> Warning: include(D:/xampp/htdocs../includes/navMain.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\adamsProject\pages\contactUs.php on line 4
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'D:/xampp/htdocs../includes/navMain.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\adamsProject\pages\contactUs.php on line 4

It says no such file in blah blah blah directory. Thing is, it has! In fact, the error is pointing to the right direction.

Comment: echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to see where your web-server root is first. Also your on windows so you might have the "\"-back slashes instead of "/"-forward slashes for the path string at the end.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. This one shows up after echoing: D:/xampp/htdocs. What does that suppose to mean.

Comment: It means your web-server's (apache) public directory (root-directory) is anything inside of the inside htdocs directory... so append the path starting at htdocs, so for example if you had a file you wanted to include at "D:/xampp/htdocs/includes/navMain.php" then you would just would just append "/includes/navMain.php" string. I use linux but I believe for windows you will need to use backslashes instead of forward slashes.

Comment: Your files are inside of htdocs right?

Comment: Yup. Here is the localtion: http://localhost/adamsProject/pages/contactUs.php I'm trying to include navMain.php in the contactUs.php page. But when I use the simple <?php include "../includes/navMain.php;"  ?> codes inside contactUs.php page, other files don't work. Such as the css and images included in the navMain.php.

Comment: Put them inside of htdocs/ ---there is web-server settings in the WAMP GUI where you can change the root directory to where ever you want but by default it's htdocs.

Comment: Yup. All my files are in the right locations already. It's the code for linking of the files inside the root folder **adamsProject** which has also subfolders namely **includes**, **pages**, **css**, ect that we need.

Comment: Ok well if localhost is htdocs then you should write it like "/adamsProject/includes/navMain.php"

Comment: I have written my code like this in the **contactUs.php** page: `<?php require_once "../includes/navMain.php;" ?>`. Everything seems to work fine. Except for the css and the images file included in the **navMain.php** that cannot seems to be carried on to the **contactUs.php** page.

Comment: Yeah you could use ../ to go back a dir but just know doing this way if you change the location of either file the link will break but its fine for now. If everything but the images are pulling over then the image path is wrong.

Comment: Ok. What line of codes do you use to link all files in the subfolders withou breaking some other files like css and images?

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for php, but for HTML use the <base> tag in HTML head, and set the base tag to your root directory "/" then you can just specify for example "/img/logo.png" or whatever path to the image you want for the img url.

Comment: You mean this: `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/navMain.php";` It returned and error like this `Warning: require_once(D:/xampp/htdocs/includes/navMain.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\adamsProject\pages\contactUs.php on line 4`

Comment: Yea you need to do "/adamsProject/include/navMain.php" and are you sure you don't have a folder called htdocs on your (D) hard drive "xampp/htdocs/" the error msg says it can"t find contactUs.php as well as the navMain.php

Comment: The folder that I have in the D: drive is xampp inside it is the htdocs. Inside the htdocs is the adamsProject folder. Inside adamsProject is the pages. Inside the pages is the contactUs.php which does not work if I tried to call the navMain.php inside the includes folder. Again, it's the css and images link that don't work in the contactUs.php.

Comment: Okay thank for clarifying that for me. Typically you won't have the image problem on an actual remote server and your serving the files locally it's little different... right click on the image and get info, use that absolute path and use it in the css for the img url. Heres what it looks like on my mac ---- background: url("/Volumes/HDISC/Users/jordandavis/Desktop/stackoverflow/img/stripes.jpg");

Comment: Hey, try checking this out: `www.adamsproject.ph` -- that is my website. Now, I'm trying to put the nav to the contact us page using php include. Problem is the logo and the other styling are messed up. I suspect it's the links.

Comment: ok let me take a look

Comment: It's your inline <style> tags they need to be in the head not the body... you should create a header.php where and add everything you need in that file and simply include it at the top.

Comment: I'll posted an example in answer below.

Comment: [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd)

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra .. At the end that is making the path invalid. When only printing $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] what is the path?

You may be able to use dirname( __FILE__ ) to get the path of the current file, then use ../ to go back each directory until you reach includes.

Comment: I've used this procedure before. It did not work. Right now, I'm trying to put the navMain.php to the ContactUs.php page. Both of them are in the subfoders. Now putting these line of code: <?php include "../includes/navMain.php"; ?>  to the contactUs.php page don't work. Because it is breaking the links of the css and images files of the navMain.php. That's the only problem. CSS and images files are messed up when you try to connect subdirectory files to subdirectory files.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the head.php opens the `<html>` and `<body>` tags and footer.php closes them.

The point of using the includes is so there is no need to duplicate the HTML code on every page. You can simply just include it on any one you need, so things that would stay the same across the site I would assume would be the header and footer, whereas each page's content will differ and you can declare that in individual files (main,contact,services,about,etc).

//MAIN.PHP

```
<?php   
include('head.php');
include('header.php');
?>
//PAGE SPECIFIC CONTENT
<header></header>
<section></section>
<?php   
include('footer.php');
?>
```

//HEAD.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HOME | ADAMS Project</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tablet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontAwesome/css/fontAwesome.min.css">
        <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,500,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryMin.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/roundAbout.js"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/galleryInit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/roundAboutShapes.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
```

//HEADER.PHP

```
 <header>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
 </header>
```

//FOOTER.PHP

```
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work! Let me try a little tweaking here.